# Disable zoom out on PhotoSwipe

Tags: javascript, zooming, photoswipe

Is there any way to disable zoom out function on clicking on photo in PhotoSwipe JS library?

When clicked on specific photo my code goes directly to zoomed in version of photo (to original size) with `applyZoomPan` method.

```
var openPhotoSwipe = function(index) {
  var pswpElement = document.querySelectorAll('.pswp')[0];
  var options = {
    history: false,
    focus: false,
    showAnimationDuration: 0,
    hideAnimationDuration: 0,
    zoomEl: false,
    maxSpreadZoom: 1,
    getDoubleTapZoom: function(isMouseClick, item) {
      return 1;
    },
    pinchToClose: false
  };

  var gallery = new PhotoSwipe( pswpElement, PhotoSwipeUI_Default, items, options);
  gallery.init();
  gallery.goTo(index);
  gallery.applyZoomPan(1, 0, 0);
};
```

I expect that user will not be able to click on zoomed in photo. The only way user can get out of zoomed in photo is by clicking X.

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires editing photoswipe-ui-default.js, but it is not hard to do. You'll need to make a fork or host the file locally.

In photoswipe-ui-default.js, add a line, and comment out some lines:

```
    ui.onGlobalTap = function(e) {
        e = e || window.event;
        var target = e.target || e.srcElement;

        if(_blockControlsTap) {
            return;
        }

        if(e.detail && e.detail.pointerType === 'mouse') {

            // close gallery if clicked outside of the image
            if(_hasCloseClass(target)) {
                pswp.close();
                return;
            }

            if(framework.hasClass(target, 'pswp__img')) {
                // !!!ADD THE FOLLOWING LINE
                pswp.close();
                // !!!COMMENT THESE LINES OUT
                //if(pswp.getZoomLevel() === 1 && pswp.getZoomLevel() <= pswp.currItem.fitRatio) {
                //  if(_options.clickToCloseNonZoomable) {
                //      pswp.close();
                //  }
                //} else {
                //  pswp.toggleDesktopZoom(e.detail.releasePoint);
                //}
            }
```

And for good measure, in the same file, you can comment out the double tap zoom function:

```
        // toggle zoom on double-tap
        //_listen('doubleTap', function(point) {
        //  var initialZoomLevel = pswp.currItem.initialZoomLevel;
        //  if(pswp.getZoomLevel() !== initialZoomLevel) {
        //      pswp.zoomTo(initialZoomLevel, point, 333);
        //  } else {
        //      pswp.zoomTo(_options.getDoubleTapZoom(false, pswp.currItem), point, 333);
        //  }
        //});
```

Then in your CSS add:

```
.pswp--zoom-allowed .pswp__img {
  cursor: default !important
}
```